# get time from datetime series in pandas 0.13.1

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

Hello I'm (still) using pandas 0.13.1

Is there a *time only* data type in Pandas, and how do I get it from a *datetime* series? Considering e.g. the following code,

```
dtim = date_range( start='10-MAR-2016', end='10-NOV-2016 23:45', freq='15T')
```

... I imagine that I should be able to do something like

```
tim = dtim.get_time()
```

Yes I have looked around [pandas timeseries documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/timeseries.html) and found a lot of details but strange enough not anything for this simple need.

I imagine I probably miss the point somehow, but can't find my way to the right page...

Thanks

---

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I need a time value that can be used in an arithmetic expression, specifically to calculate a daily sinusoid e.g.

```
sinTrend = ampli * sin( dtim.time * np.pi / 12 + phi )
```

Comment: Do you need `print (dtim.time)`?

Comment: [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.time.html?highlight=time#pandas.DatetimeIndex.time)

Comment: Hmnm, so need convert `dtim.time` to some numeric? So what is desired output from `dtim` ?

Comment: One possible solution is convert datetime to timedelta and then to seconds - `print (pd.to_timedelta(dtim.values).total_seconds())`. Is it what you need?

Comment: @Jezrael: I need a number in a known unit, e.g. days or hours, that can be divided by another number meaning "half a day" (if unit is hours, the number will be 12).

Comment: Hmmm, so what is desired output from your sample `dtim` ?

Comment: @Jezrael: just the expression `pd.to_timedelta(dtim.values)` gives me the error `ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'numpy.datetime64'>` I need to have some sort of number, e.g. in hours

Comment: Yes, I use `0.19.2`, there is works perfectly, but in version `0.13.1` it can be buggy. Is not possible upgrade?

Comment: Hmmm... to go to 0.19.2 I have to  upgrade Ubuntu, still on 14.04

Answer (score 0):

So.. I figured it out. To get a *numerical time* is as simple as evaluating the expression:

```
tim = dtim.hour + dtim.minute/60
```

This gives the time in hours.

I expected there was a specific method for this, but this is good enough, compact and meaningful.

Thanks to all